# Boundary value problem:

Tags: boundary-value-problem

I have the following Boundary value problem:

find f(x,z) that satisfies:

$g(x){df(x,z)\over dz}+A{df^2(x,z)\over dzdx}+B{df(x,z)\over dx}+Cf(x,z)=0$

where g(x) is a given function.
and the Boundary conditions are:
f(0,z)=h(z),
f(x,0)=constant

any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Could you maybe use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make you post more readable?